# what is the meaning of the <= (less than or equal) operator for boolean operations?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I saw a piece of java code like this:

```
int y = 100;
boolean x = y <= 0;
System.out.println(x);
```

`<=` is strange for me due to this using way, Could anyone explain the `<=` here, how can I use it?

Comment: It is called 'less than or equal to'

Comment: @Zavior I know it's "less than or equal to", how could it be written like this style for assigning value to boolean x; For me, I would write: x = (y <= 0 ? false : true)

Comment: Why create monster like `(y <= 0 ? false : true) ` if you could use `!(y<=0)` or even simpler `y > 0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assignment operator `=` is of [lower precedence in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `<=`, so `<=` is performed first.  The `boolean` result of `y <= 0` is assigned to `x`.  It could have more clearly written:

```
boolean x = (y <= 0);
```

But the effect is the same.

Comment: That's why I am confused due to un-clear with Priority for(= and <=) , I used to write like this : x = (y <= 0? true: false)  @rgettman

Answer (score 5):

Read it as:

```
boolean x = (y <= 0);
```

This means that:

- x will be true if y is equal to or less than zero.
- x will be false if y is greater strictly than zero.